# When saving layer edits, rings get filled in

Tags: qgis, editing, multi-polygon

Recently we updated to the new QGIS Bialowieza. I recently got the following problem:
edit layer<add ring< select the polygon and add the ring (the edit looks fine now)<save layer edits (the ring gets filled in with a multipolygon part with the same attributes as the selected polygon)
[image: screen before saving layer edits. The ring added to make the hatched polygon visible looks fine][image: screen after saving layer edits. A multipart is added on top of the hatched feature. as seen 2 polygons are selected on the same location]

I work on Windows 10. Both the workspace and the shapefiles are placed locally. Things I tried:

- The problem persists in a multipolygonZ and multipolygonZM layer but not in a simple multipolygon layer. Alas I need the Z-values.
- I can edit the layer just fine in older versions of QGIS (I tried Las Palmas and Coruna)but when I import the layer back to bialowieza, edit and save, it fills in all the rings.
- Exported to geopackage, and once again to shp but the problem stays the same.
- Everything was working fine until last week. Before, in exactly the same project, I could add rings without problems.
- Not directly as bad as the ring-problem but maybe related: when using the vertex editor it sometimes 'jumps' the edited nodes to completely different points, select different vertexes, gives it nan-values, etc. Usually stopping the editing session or reopening the QGIS project, solves this problem though, unlike the 'add ring' problem.